# Standard form posting with jQuery to php does not get all index values?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, http-post

I'm trying to submit the form to php but somehow I do not get all data passed to php?

jQuery that initialized the post is this:

```
var fieldsdata = $('form').serialize()
$.post( "index.php",  fieldsdata, function(data){
    console.log( data );
});
```

.. the fieldsdata variable that I try to send to server is this (I test this in the console)

```
[
  {
    "name": "form_key",
    "value": "FEYzybQEfJjTkzAI"
  },
  {
    "name": "shipment_item_3",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "shipment[items][3]_1",
    "value": "21"
  },
  {
    "name": "shipment[items][3]_2",
    "value": "22"
  },
  {
    "name": "shipment[items][3]_3",
    "value": "31"
  },
  {
    "name": "shipment[items][3]_4",
    "value": "42"
  },
  {
    "name": "warehouse-shipment[items][3]_1",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "warehouse-shipment[items][3]_2",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "warehouse-shipment[items][3]_3",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "warehouse-shipment[items][3]_4",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "lotnumber-shipment[items][3][1]_1",
    "value": "4"
  },
  {
    "name": "lotnumber-shipment[items][3][1]_2",
    "value": "5"
  },
  {
    "name": "lotnumber-shipment[items][3][1]_3",
    "value": "5"
  },
  {
    "name": "lotnumber-shipment[items][3][1]_4",
    "value": "6"
  },
  {
    "name": "shipment_item_4",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "shipment[items][4]_1",
    "value": "7"
  },
  {
    "name": "warehouse-shipment[items][4]_1",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "lotnumber-shipment[items][4][1]_1",
    "value": "7"
  },
  {
    "name": "shipment[comment_text]",
    "value": ""
  }
]
```

When I execute this call I'm monitoring the network tab in inspector and I can confirm that the form data that I send to server is correct:

[image]

and I only have one line of code inside index.php file,, just to debug this info:

```
var_dump($_POST);die('e');
```

and this is what I get:

```
/var/www/html/inventory174/index.php:27:
array (size=6)
  'form_key' => string 'FEYzybQEfJjTkzAI' (length=16)
  'shipment_item_3' => string '' (length=0)
  'shipment' => 
    array (size=2)
      'items' => 
        array (size=2)
          3 => string '42' (length=2)
          4 => string '7' (length=1)
      'comment_text' => string '' (length=0)
  'warehouse-shipment' => 
    array (size=1)
      'items' => 
        array (size=2)
          3 => string '1' (length=1)
          4 => string '1' (length=1)
  'lotnumber-shipment' => 
    array (size=1)
      'items' => 
        array (size=2)
          3 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          4 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
  'shipment_item_4' => string '' (length=0)
e
```

I see that for example this variable `shipment[items][3]_x` does not pass all keys but only two.. I guess that I'm facing somekind of variable name convention limit but don's know what,, if someone can take fresh look on this data that would help alot!

Also I have tested is my form valid, like this: $('edit_form').checkValidity() and I get `true` back.. so I guess that's ok

UPDATE1: add form markup -> https://jsfiddle.net/zfn98tha/1/
UPDATE2: output from $_REQUEST -> https://jsfiddle.net/zfn98tha/2/

Comment: Show us the markup for the form.

Comment: can you check the print_r($_REQUEST) in your php file

Comment: I added form and print_r output in question .. thx

Comment: Can you control the input names in the form? I would name them different: `shipment[items][3][x]` instead of `shipment[items][3]_x`. This way the field names will be well formatted, as an array, and you will get all indexes.

Comment: Please include the mark up as @JayBlanchard stated

Comment: @MisterPositive I added jsfiddle link in the question..

Comment: @moni_dragu I will try that but I think that I teste that also and that didn't work also, but will check and get back to you,,

Comment: hey @moni_dragu you are right! I changed the input names on the form to be in the form of 'array' and it worked! if you want post the answer so I can give you a vote.. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are posting the data to php you need to format the form field names as a valid array structure. Rename `shipment[items][3]_x` to `shipment[items][3][x]` and you should get all indexes.